# Changing WordPress URL breaks some jquery functions

Tags: jquery, migration

Old URL: http://www.pillerdesigns.com/foxterrier/

New URL: http://www.foxterrier.com/

Process: copied all files to new server, updated wp-config.php, changed site and WordPress URL in Settings, exported DB using phpMyAdmin then imported DB using phpMyAdmin.

Issue: Three things no longer work on new site, and it seems they are all jQuery based:

- Slideshows in header (left and right image boxes) no longer transition
- jQuery masonry no longer arranges lavender area posts
- NextGen gallery plugin no longer works

Can anyone help? Thanks!

Comment: Well, it appears it was a combination of permissions issues, invalid code, and plugin settings being reset. All fixed now, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

There are PHP errors and notices in your scripts invalidating the JavaScript code:

http://www.foxterrier.com/wp-content/themes/shape/smooths/getimages.php

```
<b>Deprecated</b>:  Function eregi() is deprecated in <b>/home/foxterrier/public_html/wp-content/themes/shape/smooths/getimages.php</b> on line <b>13</b><br />
smootharray[0]="004.jpg";<br />
```

Plus, you are loading jQuery too late. Read [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) and how to handle dependencies (the third parameter).

Comment: Such is the problem with using `WP_DEBUG` in production ...

Comment: @EAMann Using `eregi()` in production isn’t better. :D

Comment: I've enqueued my jquery scripts and the problem remains. And why does everything work on the old URL with the same code? It's strange--the problems will occur on the old URL as well the moment I update the WordPress URL in Settings.